# Win32 Scrollbar : When drag horizontal scroll bar to right most position, value of nPos doesn't reach nMaxPos

Tags: c, winapi

I'm new to win32 API. I need to use scroll bar for moving screen for viewing certain graph drawing. Let assume my X axis is 1500 unit length(pixel?). I have initialize my scroll bar as below:

```
SCROLLINFO  si; 

si.cbSize = sizeof (si) ;
si.fMask  = SIF_ALL;
si.nMin   = 0 ;
si.nMax   = 1500 ;
si.nPage  = 100 ;
SetScrollInfo (hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE) ;
```

Also i have handle case for WM_SIZE and WM_HSCROLL as follow:

```
case WM_SIZE:
    SetScrollRange(hwnd, SB_HORZ, 0, 1500, TRUE);


case WM_HSCROLL:
    GetScrollInfo (hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si) ;
    iPosBeforeScroll = si.nPos ;
    iWindowShiftPerScrollClick = 1;
    switch (LOWORD (wParam))
    {
        case SB_LINELEFT:   // press left button
            si.nPos -= iWindowShiftPerScrollClick ;
            xShift = -iWindowShiftPerScrollClick;
            break ;

        case SB_LINERIGHT:  // press right button
             si.nPos += iWindowShiftPerScrollClick ;
             xShift = iWindowShiftPerScrollClick;
             break ;
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
              si.nPos = si.nTrackPos ;
              xShift = si.nTrackPos - iPosBeforeScroll;
              break;
    }
    si.fMask = SIF_ALL ;
    SetScrollInfo (hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE) ;
    GetScrollInfo (hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si) ;
    ScrollWindow (hwnd, -xShift, 0, NULL, NULL) ;
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

When i run the program, I have observe that, when scroll bar is moved to the right most position, the value of **si.nPos** is only reach **1401**. Shouldn't it be **1500** as I have set range to **1500**? also, when scroll bar is at right most position, i can still press scroll bar move right button, the screen is shifted but scroll bar remain at same place. I can press scroll bar right button till **nPos** reach maximum (1500 in my case).

My Questions are:

1> Is what happen above normal? If yes, how can i calculate what value of nPos will be when i drag scroll bar to maximum limit for given range?

2> Is one unit movement in scroll bar equivalent to one unit movement (pixel) in its window drawing?

**UPDATE:**

Just observe that the scroll bar can be dragged only up to "nMaxPos - 99". This partly answer my first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To question 1:
This is completely documented in [SetScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

The relevant factor here is the page size.

From the docs:

> The SetScrollInfo function performs range checking on the values
>   specified by the nPage and nPos members of the SCROLLINFO structure.
>   The nPage member must specify a value from 0 to nMax - nMin +1. The
>   nPos member must specify a value between nMin and nMax - max( nPage–
>   1, 0). If either value is beyond its range, the function sets it to a
>   value that is just within the range.

To question 2:
It depends on what you are doing. And in fact no: 1. tick in the scrollbar may be 1 row in a scrollbar (Listbox, tree control etc.) . Or 1 logical point if you use GDI mapping modes.
The scrollbar does what ever you want. As long as the scrollbar is not bound to an existing control (ListCtrl, TreeCtrl, Edit Ctrl)

Comment: Thank you. u were right. I didn't thought nPage could have any relation with scroll position. :)